# Loaded Keras model from .h5 file is not predicting correctly like the original one after training

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, classification

I am new to ML and I am trying to play a little with this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@ferhat00/deep-learning-with-keras-classifying-cats-and-dogs-part-2-21b3b25bbe5c . Anyway, the CNN seems to work only in the case I don't save it in an h5 file after the training. More precisely:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import optimizers

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (128, 128, 3), activation = 'relu'))


classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


classifier.add(Flatten())


classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('PetImages/training_set',
                                             target_size = (128, 128),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('PetImages/test_set',
                                        target_size = (128, 128),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 8000/32,
                     epochs = 30,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = 2000/32, workers=12, max_q_size=100)

///////////////////////////////////////
classifier.save("cnnPetsModel.h5")
print("saved model to disk")
///////////////////////////////////////

from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
img_path = 'PetImages/test_set/Dog/5000.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(128, 128))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = classifier.predict(x)

training_set.class_indices

print(preds)
if preds[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'

print(prediction)


img_path = 'PetImages/test_set/Cat/5000.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(128, 128))
x = image.img_to_array(img)

x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = classifier.predict(x)

training_set.class_indices

print(preds)
if preds[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'

print(prediction)
```

If I remove the code between "////////", the two images are predicted correctly, while it becomes always "cat" in the case I save the model. Why this happens? I am only saving parameters, structure etc. in a file, at all...
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I moved the saving at the end of the code and the model predicts correctly. Anyway, if such a model is loaded from another python file and then used for predict(x) like above, it results in an untrained one which always returns "cat".

Comment: I think this is related to running your code in cells, threading and that saving a model is taking long time, so it looks like training is done but saving the model blocks the current trained model from being used, so when you predict in another cell it uses a previous not trained model. 
So I think you should wait a while and check that saving is done

Comment: I moved the saving at the end of the code and it predicts correctly. Anyway, if the model is loaded from another python file and then used for predict(x) like above, it results in an untrained one which always returns "cat"